# Export blendshapes to JSON error

Tags: export, shape-keys, three.js

Blender 2.76 / Three js export addon 1.5

Addon crash after exporting blendshapes! Why?

[image]

Comment: A cursory glance and it appears you have no shapekey animation, `action is None`.  Try adding a keyframe on one of the shapes.  If I don't get beaten to it, will elaborate with an answer. Quick solution would be to disable  that field in UI while there is no shape animation.

Comment: I added keyframe - thаt helped, thanks. But morphs saved in another file.

Comment: Property "embed animation" save morphs in one file. Solved!

Comment: Glad you were able to solve this, could you add your solution as an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 step: add a keyframe on your scene

2 step: enable the "Embed animation" checkbox